# How to sort Windows 7 taskbar thumbnail previews?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, sorting, thumbnails, preview

Here is a screenshot of the list of windows I have stacked in my Windows 7 taskbar. This is just for Explorer, but similarly I have lots of stacked windows of other processes as well.

[image: screenshot]

Currently these stacks of windows are sorted in the order they were opened. All I want is to sort this stack of windows by their title so it's easier to look for them.

Superusers, can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't **Jump Lists**, they are **Taskbar thumbnail previews**. The Win Explorer Jump List looks like this when multiple windows are open:

[image: 1]

When there are too many windows open and consequently too many thumbnails to fit on screen, the list changes to a simple text-based one as shown in the question's screenshot. Windows 7 and later use [**Application User Model IDs (AppUserModelIDs)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459%28VS.85%29.aspx) to determine which windows to group/combine and which ones to treat separately. It *is* possible to sort windows within a group, but unfortunately Windows only allows window groups as a whole to be moved on the taskbar. However, a handy utility that provides the missing UI for various taskbar-related options/operations is [**7+ Taskbar Tweaker**](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) (can be installed in portable mode):

[image: 2]

As you can see from the screenshot above, you can either select **Drag to reorder** under **Thumbnails** to allow for simple dragging of thumbnail previews, or open the **Taskbar Inspector**, right-click the relevant window group and select the **Sort group items** option.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is called **Windows 7 Jump Lists**, so renaming the title might help you find a better answer. The Jump List is made just to give you a quick access to the last used items. So the answer is no, you can't sort the folders or items in the Jump List of Windows 7. You can just increase the number of last used folders in your Jump List, but i see you already did that.

Windows 7 stores the Jump List files in this location:

`C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`

But there are a lot of third party Jump List programs for Windows 7. Maybe some offer what you need. I know [Jumplist Extender](https://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender/) and [Lump Launcher](http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/).

Comment: I don't think this is same as Jump Lists. Jump Lists are what you see on right clicking those program icons in the taskbar. I am simply hovering on top of those icons.

Comment: Are you sure? Cause it looks like Windows 7 Jump List. So you have opened 30 folders and when you hover over the explorer icon in the taskbar you see the image above you provided ? That is just a preview of your open programs you can't sort that. It will always display in order you opened the files.